# How to extract href and the linked text or tag out of an <a> tag in the shell?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a lot of HTML files with a lot of different content where I'm extracting always a specific part of it with a command line tool called `pup`. The extract contains sometimes  tags which can look like this:

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="someclasses">anchor text</a>
```

... or like this:

```
<a class="someclasses" href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" target="_blank" js-class>
Visit Duck Duck Go!
</a>
```

... or even like this:

```
<a class="someclasses"
    href="mailto:this.is.an@email.com" js-class>
    email

</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is to ...

1. ... extract href value and anchor-text (the text between `<a ...>` and `</a>`).
2. ... put both extracts in a seperate line but in the reverse order: First the text, than the href value.
3. ... put three characters in front of every href value: `=>`

So the result looks for example like this:

```
Visit Duck Duck Go!
=> https://www.duckduckgo.com
```

I'm able to get what I want with some concatinated `sed` commands and some RegEx by creating groups/patterns and switching their printed order, if everything is in one line, just like in the first example. But I have no clue how to get what I want if the anchor tag is spred over several lines. I tried to achive my goal only with `sed` but I had no luck. Yesterday I've been reading about similar problems from other people and that `sed`is not ment to work over a linebreak beyond. Is this true? Could `awk` do this? Are there any other tools I could use?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: I have a feeling pup should be able to do this, and if not, you can always convert to JSON using pup, and then use something like jq to robustly extract it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done parsing HTML fragments with `xmllint` and `xpath` expressions

```
frag=$(cat <<EOF
<div>
<a class="someclasses"
    href="mailto:this.is.an@email.com" js-class>
    email

</a>
<a class="someclasses"
    href="http://example.com">
    URL

</a>
<a class="someclasses"
    href="http://example.com/2">
    URL 2

</a>
</div>
EOF
)


while read -r line; do
    if [ "${line%=*}" == 'href' ]; then
        url=$(tr -d '"' <<<"${line#*=}")
    elif [ -n "$line" ]; then
       echo "$line"
       echo "=> $url"
    fi
done < <(echo "$frag" | xmllint --recover --html --xpath "//a/text()| //a/@href" -)
```

Result:

```
email
=> mailto:this.is.an@email.com
URL
=> http://example.com
URL 2
=> http://example.com/2
```

`xmllint` could be used to parse HTML files directly also.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s/\S` shorthand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="</a>" }
match($0,/<a[^>]+href="([^"]+).*>\s*(\S.*\S)/,a) {
    print a[2] "!" ORS "=> " a[1]
}
```

e.g. given this input file:

```
$ cat file
The extract contains sometimes tags which can look like this:

<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="someclasses">anchor text</a>

... or like this:

<a class="someclasses" href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" target="_blank" js-class>
Visit Duck Duck Go!
</a>

... or even like this:

<a class="someclasses"
    href="mailto:this.is.an@email.com" js-class>
    email

</a>
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
anchor text!
=> https://www.stackoverflow.com
Visit Duck Duck Go!!
=> https://www.duckduckgo.com
email!
=> mailto:this.is.an@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `bash` script though it may not be as efficient as the tools mentioned in the comments.

```
$ cat input_file
<a class="someclasses"
    href="mailto:this.is.an@email.com" js-class>
    email

</a>

<a class="someclasses" href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" target="_blank" js-class>
Visit Duck Duck Go!
</a>

<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="someclasses">anchor text</a>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=$'\n'
i=0
count=$(( $(sed -En 's/<.*>(.*)<.*>/\1/g;/<|>/!p' input_file | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l) - 1 ))
while [[ "$i" -le "$count" ]];
    do for f in input_file; do
        first=($(sed -En 's/<.*>(.*)<.*>/\1/g;/<|>/!p' "$f" | sed '/^$/d'))
        second=($(sed -En 's|.*href="(.[^ ]*)".*|\1|p;' "$f"))
        echo "${first[$i]}" $'\n' " => ${second[$i]}"
        ((i++))
    done
done
```

**Output**

```
email
  => mailto:this.is.an@email.com
Visit Duck Duck Go!
  => https://www.duckduckgo.com
anchor text
  => https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm able to get what I want with some concatinated `sed` commands and some RegEx by creating groups/patterns and switching their printed order, if everything is in one line, just like in the first example. But I have no clue how to get what I want if the anchor tag is spred over several lines.*

If you need to retain what you already have then consider just removing newlines before actual processing, for example using [`tr` - translate or delete characters](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) .

Comment: That should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that the output of `pup` is well-formed XML, like this:

```
<root>
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="someclasses">anchor text</a>

<a class="someclasses" href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" target="_blank" js-class="x">
Visit Duck Duck Go!
</a>

<a class="someclasses"
    href="mailto:this.is.an@email.com" js-class="x">
  email
</a>
</root>
```

This means that you need a root element, like the `root` tag in this case, and that every attribute has a value, which is the reason why I changed `js-class` into `js-class="x"`.

The `xmlstarlet` command extracting what you want is:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//a" -v "normalize-space()" -n -o "== " -v "@href" -n input.xml
```

The output corresponding to the input above is:

```
anchor text
== https://www.stackoverflow.com
Visit Duck Duck Go!
== https://www.duckduckgo.com
email
== mailto:this.is.an@email.com
```

Since `xmlstarlet` is unable to output a `>`, as far as I know, you may want to correct the `==` string into `=>` by adding a filter at the end of the command, as in:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//a" -v "normalize-space()" -n -o "== " -v "@href" -n input.xml | 
sed 's/==/=>/'
```

giving as final result:

```
anchor text
=> https://www.stackoverflow.com
Visit Duck Duck Go!
=> https://www.duckduckgo.com
email
=> mailto:this.is.an@email.com
```

But again and again: don't use `regex` and `sed` to process HTML files.